# Desktop bridge - wpftool kit dependency issue

Tags: uwp, wpftoolkit, windows-10-desktop, desktop-bridge

I have a desktop WPF application and its have the dependency of WPFToolkit binary. Currently I'm trying to convert WPF application to UWP using desktop bridge manual option.

referring the below option to do it,

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net

I got the below build issue,

> Error MSB4018 The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Item named
>   'themes/luna.normalcolor.baml' of type
>   'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' cannot be added to the resource file
>   because it is not serializable.    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo
>   reader, IResourceWriter writer)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.WriteResources(ReaderInfo
>   reader, String filename)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.ProcessFile(String inFile,
>   String outFileOrDir)    at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ProcessResourceFiles.Run(TaskLoggingHelper log,
>   ITaskItem[] assemblyFilesList, List`1 inputs, List`1 satelliteInputs,

if anybody faced the same issue, please reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used manual packaging to resolve the issue. 
referred the below link,
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41b07aef-b3e6-47fa-b5c6-a390af2e2194/uwp-desktop-bridge-embedding-dlls-in-appx-package?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 0):

From a little research i did, it seems that this style is not supported anymore, in fact, it is as old as Aero, even if you managed to bypass the error, the app wouldn't work.

Comment: yes, it seems that this theme is not supported. so need to remove the dependency of wpftoolkit from the wpf application. is it the correct solution?

Comment: yeah , also change the theme of any control that is using it. Blend for visual studio has an interface for managing WPF apps, and its much like the uwp one, just look up each control and make sure they use current colors and themes

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.

[Baml error in Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-known-issues)

Add the following to the first PropertyGroup of your csproj file.

```
<AppxGeneratePrisForPortableLibrariesEnabled>false</AppxGeneratePrisForPortableLibrariesEnabled>
```

Comment: As a side note, in older versions of windows baml issues could occur when you are using the old Lunar Olive Theme.